# Can't break out from while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

I am an absolute beginner in python, here's the code I'm having trouble with.
So the problem is that when i press 0 the loop doesn't break

```
while True:
idiot = input('Continue Y/N?: ')
idiot = idiot.upper()
if idiot == ('Y'):
    print('Great')
if idiot == ('N'):
    print('okey')
if idiot == 0:
    print('exit')
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure that you indent your code correctly so that answerers can read and help. (Or, if that is the indentation of your code, then make sure you indent things in a while loop!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `True` never changes to `False` which would end the loop.

Changing the last `if` clause to `if str(idiot) == '0'` will do the trick because `input()` always returns a `str` and you provided an `int` (0 instead of '0').

```
while True:
    idiot = input('Continue Y/N?: ')
    idiot = idiot.upper()
    if idiot == ('Y'):
        print('Great')
    if idiot == ('N'):
        print('okey')
    if idiot == '0':
        print('exit')
        break
```

Anyway
I always use `while` loops with a variable that contains a boolean (True / False).

With the variable `TrueOrFalse` I could set it to `False` once a condition is met.

this is how I would have done it:

```
TrueOrFalse = True
while TrueOrFalse:
    idiot = input('Continue Y/N?: ')
    idiot = idiot.upper()
    if idiot == ('Y'):
        print('Great')
    if idiot == ('N'):
        print('okey')
    if idiot == '0':
        TrueOrFalse = False
        print('exit')
```

One more thing: I know this is just an example but your `input()` is only asking for 'Y' or 'N' and '0' is missing. Anyway I guess the 'N' should do (exit the loop) what the '0' is doing now.